# Zend Framework cannot get helper, even though it is list in existing helpers

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've previously created an action helper `Website_Layout_ActionHelper` which extends `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract` and has a `getName` method which returns "layoutSelector".

This helper has been working fine for years along with several other helpers that have been put together, although none of them call on any of the others.

I'm now trying to create a new action helper which the layout helper needs to call on.

The new action helper is `Website_UserInfo_ActionHelper` - it is set up in practically the same way as the other helpers (file paths, etc), and has a `getName` method returning `userInfo`.

However, when I try to access the new helper from my layout helper, I get the following exceptions:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'UserInfo' in /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336
>
> Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception: Plugin by name 'UserInfo' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_: Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ in /usr/share/php/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php on line 424
>
> Zend_Controller_Action_Exception: Action Helper by name UserInfo not found in /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php on line 369

However, when I dump the array from `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelpers()` instead of trying to call `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getHelper('userInfo')` the userInfo helper is there...

The fact that the error messages are capitalising the UserInfo name is probably a clue, but I don't understand why I'm getting this behaviour when all the other helpers are happily working. Is it because I'm trying to access the helper from inside another helper? Because in my reading, this should be possible.

So, the question: why do I get exceptions when trying get a helper from the broker when the helper is actually loaded?

Comment: What is the call in your old (Layout) helper by which you are attempting to access an instance of the new (UserInfo) helper?

Comment: I've tried both `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getHelper('userInfo')` and through the frontController

Comment: How about `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getHelper('UserInfo')` ?

Comment: How about the actual filename of the helper? Is it `userInfo.php` (which I suspect would fail to load) or `UserInfo.php` (which I suspect is what the loader is looking for) ?

Comment: But the name is userInfo. That is the key in the array of existing helpers and what getName returns.

Comment: File name is UserInfo.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116476/discussion-between-david-weinraub-and-horuskol).